# Python - Client sometimes never receives data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, data-loss, python-3.5

I'm making a small client/server game. While it mostly seems working, the communication between the server and client seems slightly funky and I'm not quite sure what's causing it.

So, I launch the `server.py` followed by the `client.py`, the client connects and receives the length of the first message, it receives the actual message and displays it perfectly fine. But when it runs through again, it never gets the second message, only how long it is. It just waits indefinitely (well, for TCPs timeout duration I guess).

I understand some bytes can get lost, but TCP is meant to guarantee the delivery if there's a connection still, right? UDP is the one that just throws out the packets? It doesn't seem to be disconnecting either. This is all over localhost too, so it's not even leaving my machine.

In case it was to do with timing, I also made the server `time.sleep(.5)` before waiting for a reply back from the client user input.

Why is the client getting the first message but not the second despite using the same method to send it?

**Server.py**

```
import socket, random, pickle, os.path, csv, time

# Global variables
c = 0
a = ""

def SendIt(d):
    global c
    d = pickle.dumps(d)
    MSGLEN = len(d)
    print ("MSGLEN =", MSGLEN) # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
    MSGLENstr = pickle.dumps(MSGLEN)
    c.send(MSGLENstr)
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < MSGLEN:
        sent = c.send(d[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent

def TheMainGame():
    def within(val, goal):
        i = abs(val - goal)
        if (i <= 3):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def try_int(k):
        try:
            return int(k)
        except ValueError:
            return k

    def GetScoreboard():
        with open('Scores.csv', 'r') as scores:
            reader = csv.reader(scores)
            tscores = [[str(e) for e in r] for r in reader if len(r) > 0]
            return tscores

    def WriteScore(gscore):
        global c, a, tscore
        exists = os.path.isfile("Scores.csv")
        if (exists == False): # Checks if file exists, if not create it
            nscore = [[gscore, a[0]]] # Add first line of data
            with open("Scores.csv", "a") as scores:
                writer = csv.writer(scores)
                [writer.writerow(r) for r in nscore]
        else: # File exists so we add to it
            nscore = [[gscore, a[0]]]
            with open('Scores.csv', 'r') as scores:
                reader = csv.reader(scores)
                tscores = [[str(e) for e in r] for r in reader if len(r) > 0]
            tscores = [[try_int(l) for l in i] for i in tscores]
            tscores.append(nscore[0])
            tscores = [x for x in tscores if x != []]
            tscores.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
            if (len(tscores) > 5):
                tscores = tscores[:5]
                with open("Scores.csv", "w+") as scores:
                    writer = csv.writer(scores)
                    [writer.writerow(r) for r in tscores]
            elif (len(tscores) <= 5):
                with open("Scores.csv", "w+") as scores:
                    writer = csv.writer(scores)
                    [writer.writerow(r) for r in tscores]

    def Guess():
        global c
        guesses = 0
        while True:
            data = ["open", "What is your guess?"]
            SendIt(data)
            time.sleep(.5)
            print("sent question") # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
            t = int(c.recv(1000).decode())
            print("waiting for reply") # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
            if (t == x):
                guesses += 1
                data = ["msg","Correct!"]
                SendIt(data)
                if (guesses == 1):
                    msg = "You took ", guesses, " guess!"
                else:
                    msg = "You took ", guesses, " guesses!"
                msg = [str(x) for x in msg]
                msg = ",".join(msg)
                msg = msg.replace(",", "")
                data = ["msg", msg]
                SendIt(data)
                WriteScore(guesses)
                data = ["msg", "Heres the leaderboard:"]
                SendIt(data)
                data = ["scores", GetScoreboard()]
                SendIt(data)
                data = ["closing", "Thanks for playing!"]
                SendIt(data)
                c.close()
                break
            elif (within(t,x) == True):
                guesses += 1
                data = ["incorrect", "Close!"]
                SendIt(data)
            elif (within(t,x) == False):
                guesses += 1
                data = ["incorrect", "Far"]
                SendIt(data)
            else:
                data = ["closing", "There was an error computing the value"]
                SendIt(data)
                c.close()
                break

    x = random.randrange(1, 20, 1)
    print(x) # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
    Guess()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4001))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    (c,a) = s.accept()
    data = ["msg", "Hello user!"]
    SendIt(data)
    TheMainGame()
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket, pickle

# Global variables
connected = False
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
data = ["closing", "Connection closed"]

def GetData():
    global s, data
    chunks = []
    bytes_recd = 0
    MSGLEN = s.recv(512) # OLD RECV
    MSGLEN = pickle.loads(MSGLEN)
    print ("MSGLEN =", MSGLEN) # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
    while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
        chunk = s.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
        print("chunk =", chunk) # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        chunks.append(chunk)
        bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
    data =  b''.join(chunks)
    data = pickle.loads(data)
    print("data after depickled=", data) # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG

def SendData():
    global s
    sdata = input()
    s.send(sdata.encode())


def Connect():
    global s, connected
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4001))
    connected = True

# Connect to server
Connect()

# Send/recive data till session ends
while (connected == True):
    print("fetching data") # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
    GetData()
    print ("got data") # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
    if (data[0] == "closing"):
        print (data[1])
        s.close()
        connected = False
        break
    elif (data[0] == "incorrect"):
        print (data[1])
    elif (data[0] == "open"):
        print("open task running") # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
        print (data[1])
        print("printed data[1]") # REMOVE AFTER DEBUG
        SendData()
    elif (data[0] == "msg"):
        print (data[1])
    elif (data[0] == "scores"):
        data = data[1]
        data = [",".join(i) for i in data]
        data = [i.replace(",", " - ") for i in data]
        print("Guesses - User")
        print(*data, sep='\n')
    else:
        print ("An error occured!")
```

**Server output**

```
MSGLEN = 36
5
MSGLEN = 45
sent question
```

**Client output**

```
fetching data
MSGLEN = 36
chunk = b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x03\x00\x00\x00msgq\x01X\x0b\x00\x00\x00Hello user!q\x02e.'
data after depickled= ['msg', 'Hello user!']
got data
Hello user!
fetching data
MSGLEN = 45
```

The server won't have any output when finished, I only put it in to help me debug. And most of the output in client won't exist either, again it's just there for debugging. I've marked all debugging lines with `# REMOVE AFTER DEBUG` to help make them easier to find. As you can see `chunk = s.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))` never completes the second time around.

Comment: Okay I fixed that problem. I just moved `time.sleep(.5)` a line up. But now I'm getting another error, a random blank message is being received causing the client to think the connection is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a logic based error that I solved myself.

I removed the `time.sleep(.5)` line in the server and moved it up into `SendIt()` altering it to `time.sleep(.1)` causing the server to sleep for 0.1 seconds before sending the data to the client. To put the into perspective:

```py
def Guess():
    global c
    guesses = 0
    while True:
        data = ["open", "What is your guess?"]
        SendIt(data)
        """time.sleep(.5)""" # This line gets removed 
        print("sent question")
        t = int(c.recv(1000).decode())
        print("waiting for reply")
```

and

```py
def SendIt(d):
    global c
    d = pickle.dumps(d)
    MSGLEN = len(d)
    print ("MSGLEN =", MSGLEN)
    MSGLENstr = pickle.dumps(MSGLEN)
    time.sleep(.1) # This new line makes it pause 0.1 seconds before sending the data
    c.send(MSGLENstr)
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < MSGLEN:
        sent = c.send(d[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent
```

Hope this helps someone else! Also remember to `import time`.